# How do you check if there is a unique element in a matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, unique, nested-loops

I need help in making a program to check whether there is a unique element in a matrix or none at all.
First, the program asks for the number of the rows and columns. Then it asks for the elements of the matrix.
If there is a unique element found in the matrix, then it prints "Unique element found."
If there is no unique element, then it prints "No unique element."

```
int rows, cols;
 printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
 scanf("%d", &rows);
 printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
 scanf("%d", &cols);
 
 int matrix[rows][cols];
 for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
     for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++){
         scanf("%d", &matrix[row][col]);
     }
}
```

i appreciate the help, thank you very much.

Comment: put your matrix content into a one-dimensional array and sort it in ascending or descending order. when you iterate over the array, check if `arr[i-1]`, `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]` are equal. if they are *not*, `arr[i]` is unique

Answer (score 0):

Even n-dimensional arrays are linear in memory. You may sort a linear array inplace and look for unique elements.

```
int compare_ints(const void* a, const void* b) {
  const int arg1 = *(const int*)a;
  const int arg2 = *(const int*)b;
 
  if (arg1 < arg2) return -1;
  if (arg1 > arg2) return 1;
  return 0;
 
  // return (arg1 > arg2) - (arg1 < arg2); // possible shortcut
  // return arg1 - arg2; // erroneous shortcut (fails if INT_MIN is present)
}

// ... your Q code here

const size_t n = rows * cols;
int* arr = (int*)matrix;
qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), compare_ints);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
    puts("No unique element.");
    return;
  }
}
puts("Unique element found.");
```

Comment: Actually the shortcut fails for any `arg2 >= arg1 - INT_MIN`.

Comment: Should be noted *explicitly* that this approach *modifies* the matrix, though – in case of still needing the original matrix, we thus need to create a copy. I like the O(n*log(n)) idea, but I expect the constants getting pretty large, so we might benefit from only with pretty large matrices...

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward approach is to interpret the matrix as a one-dimensional array

For example

```
int unique = 0;
size_t n = rows * cols;
int *a = ( int * ) matrix;

for ( size_t i = 0; !unique && i < n; i++ )
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) ++j;

    if ( j++ == i )
    {
        while ( j != n && a[j] != a[i] ) ++j;

        unique = j == n;
    }
}  

if ( unique ) puts( "Unique element found." );
else puts( "No unique element." );
```

To get the row and the column of the unique element all you need is to declare the variable `i` outside the nested loops. For example

```
int *a = ( int * ) matrix;
int unique = 0;
size_t n = rows * cols;
size_t i = 0;

for ( ; !unique && i < n; i += !unique )
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) ++j;

    if ( j++ == i )
    {
        while ( j != n && a[j] != a[i] ) ++j;

        unique = j == n;
    }
}  

if ( unique ) 
{
    size_t row = i / cols;
    size_t col = i % cols;
    printf( "Unique element found at %zu row and %zu column.\n", row, col );
}
else 
{
    puts( "No unique element." );
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty complex... `for(i = 1; i<n; ++i) { for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) { if(a[i] == a[j] { goto NOT_UNIQUE; } } }` would compare all numbers against all its predecessors.

Comment: @Aconcagua The code you showed is a bad code. Do not use the goto statement.

Comment: You're pretty outdated with this attitude. Even MISRA in its recent version allows it (again). `goto` is a useful tool if used *at the right place*. Avoid it, if there are better ways. Use it, if alternatives produce hopelessly complex code. Just like an axe: You can use it to kill people, but you can use it to chop wood as well. Would you now forbid axes just because some kill people with?

Comment: *'Unconstrained use of goto can lead to programs that are extremely difficult to comprehend, analyse and, for C++, can also lead to the program exhibiting unspecified behaviour. However, in many cases a total ban on goto requires the introduction of flags to ensure correct control flow,and it is possible that these flags may themselves be less transparent than the goto they replace.'* (https://www.cppdepend.com/misra-c – secondary source, I know...).

Comment: @Aconcagua Oh, I have not known that nowadays a bad code is in fashion. Thank you.

Comment: What are the criteria for being *bad*? Simple use of `goto`? Or the fact that I needed to read your code multiple times to understand it? Apart from, if placed into a function, the goto might be replaced by `return` – oh, well, some coding conventions forbid more than one return point, too...

Comment: @Aconcagua It breaks structured code. Usually all beginners start programming with using the goto statement.  They think that this makes code simpler.:) So for example instead of loops they use the goto statement and everywhere where they can place the goto statement they place it.:)

Comment: Too much principles in my eyes... Sure, beginners use it in a bad manner (the 'killing people' case...). I'm in favour of a good balance between principles ('avoid goto') and pragmatism: *If* we can write just as clear, readable code without goto – then *do* so. But if code without is complicated, hard to understand – and even less efficient (the flag needs to be additionally checked, unless *perhaps* optimised away), *then* profit from...

Comment: Down-vote wasn't mine, by the way – and I'm not sure if justified. Even though complicated, the code at least does what it is expected to do...

Comment: @Aconcagua It seems the answer was downvoted because I did use the goto statement.:)

Comment: For sure not – because there hasn't ever been in ;)